# Can I use modulo with Array.prototype.map to insert new line every 3 indicies?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to learn es6 and playing around with the pokemon API.
myRoute = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/144/';

```
const arrObservable = this._http.get(newurl);
 arrObservable.subscribe( 
(data) => {
 const pokeString = data.pokemon.map( ( { pokemon }: obj ) => pokemon.name );
console.log(`There are ${data.pokemon.length} pokemon with the ${data.name} ability:  ${pokeString}`);
```

})

> output:
>
> There are 19 pokemon with the regenerator ability:  slowpoke,slowbro,tangela,slowking,corsola,ho-oh,tangrowth,audino,solosis,duosion,reuniclus,foongus,amoonguss,alomomola,mienfoo,mienshao,mareanie,toxapex,tornadus-therian

**I am getting the correct results**, it just looks a bit icky in the console, so I'm wondering if there is a way to add a '\n' every *few* lines while still using the .map() function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: What you actually need is `.join(", ")` - notice the space!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've used `.map`, join by commas, and then use `.replace` on the resulting string to replace instances of 3 words separated by commas with those 3 words and commas plus a newline. That way, your `pokeString` will actually be a string:

```
const pokeString = data.pokemon
  .map( ( { pokemon }: obj ) => pokemon.name )
  .join(',')
  .replace(/[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,/g, '$&\n');
```

```js
const names = ['slowpoke','slowbro','tangela','slowking','corsola','ho-oh','tangrowth','audino','solosis','duosion','reuniclus','foongus','amoonguss','alomomola','mienfoo','mienshao','mareanie','toxapex','tornadus-therian'];

const pokeString = names
  .join(',')
  .replace(/[^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+,/g, '$&\n');
  
console.log(pokeString);
```

Comment: Good hacky solution.

Comment: Thats beautiful! I'll accept in a few minutes when I'm allowed. Thanks for the quick answer!